# Making bootstrap-tags responsive, jquery events lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change this demo:
http://maxwells.github.io/bootstrap-tags.html

into a responsive version in which I can set it to readOnly and remove it from readOnly as I like. This code:

```
var alltags = ["new tag", "testtag", "tets", "wawa", "wtf", "wtf2"];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tagbox = $('#my-tag-list').tags({
            suggestions: alltags
        });
        var tagenable = true;
        $('#my-tag-list').focusout(function() {
            if (tagenable) {
                tagbox.readOnly = true;
                $('#my-tag-list').empty();
                tagbox.init();
                tagenable = false; 
            }
        });
        $('#my-tag-list').click(function() {
            if(!tagenable) {
                tagbox.readOnly = false;
                $('#my-tag-list').empty();
                tagbox.init();
                tagenable = true;
            }
        });
    });
```

seems to work fairly well, it makes everything readonly after focusout and editable when I click it. However, the editing does not work since I cannot insert new tags nor delete them (seems to be like event handling was lost or something like that).

I am guessing that emptying the #my-tag-list div is causing this, but I cannot yet find a way to use for instance "detach" instead that removes everything inside (not the element itself) and putting it back in again.

I tried to make a JS Fiddle, but it isn't really working so well yet:
http://jsfiddle.net/tomzooi/cLxz0L06/
The thing that does work is a save of the entire website, which is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ldbfqjol3pppu2k/AABhuJA4A6j9XTxUKBEzoH6za?dl=0 
this link has the unminimized JS of the bootstrap-tags stuff I am using:
https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-tags.js

Comment: Are you talking about event handlers bound to elements inside the my-Tag-List element?

Comment: I think I am, but honestly I'm not sure, not much of a JS or a Jquery specialist.

Answer (score 0):

So far I managed to do this with some modifications of the bootstrap javascript code. I use two different tagbox which I hide and unhide with some click events.

```
var tagbox = $('#my-tag-list').tags({
                suggestions: alltags,
                tagData: tmp_tags,
                afterAddingTag: function(tag) { tagboxro.addTag(tag); },
                afterDeletingTag: function(tag) {tagboxro.removeTag(tag); }
            });
            var tagboxro = $('#my-tag-listro').tags({
                suggestions: alltags,
                tagData: tmp_tags,
                readOnly: 'true',
                tagSize: 'sm',
                tagClass: 'btn-info pull-right'
            });
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var container = $("#my-tag-list");
                if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { // ... nor a descendant of the container
                if (tagsave) {              
                    $("#my-tag-listro").show();
                    $("#my-tag-list").hide();
                    var tags = tagbox.getTags();
                    $.post("%basedir%/save.php",  {
                        editorID:"new_tags",
                        tags:tags
                      }, function(data,status){
                        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    });
                        tagsave = false;
                }
                }
            });
            $('#my-tag-listro').click(function() {
                tagsave = true;
                //$(".tag-list").toggle();
                $("#my-tag-list").show();
                $("#my-tag-listro").hide();

            });
```

I had to modify the code of bootstrap-tags.js to allow for this since it normally deletes all of the usefull functions when it is considered readonly in the init function:

```
 if (this.readOnly) {
                    this.renderReadOnly();
                    this.removeTag = function(tag) {
                        if (_this.tagsArray.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
                            _this.tagsArray.splice(_this.tagsArray.indexOf(tag), 1);
                            _this.renderReadOnly();
                        }
                        return _this;
                    };
                    this.removeTagClicked = function() {};
                    this.removeLastTag = function() {};
                    this.addTag = function(tag) {
                        _this.tagsArray.push(tag);
                        _this.renderReadOnly();
                        return _this;
                    };
                    this.addTagWithContent = function() {};
                    this.renameTag = function() {};
                    return this.setPopover = function() {};
                }
```

would be awesome if this feature was incorporated in a somewhat less hacky way though :)